# Find NA values after using addNA()

Tags: r, categories, na

I have a data frame with a bunch of categorical variables.  Some of them contain NA's and I use the `addNA` function to convert them to an explicit factor level.  My problem comes when I try to treat them as NA's they don't seem to register.

Here's my example data set and attempts to 'find' NA's:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:200, y =rbinom(200, 1, .5),
                  var1 = factor(rep(c('abc','def','ghi','jkl'),50)))
df1$var2 <- factor(rep(c('ab c','ghi','jkl','def'),50))
df1$var3 <- factor(rep(c('abc','ghi','nop','xyz'),50))

df1[df1$var1 == 'abc','var1'] <- NA

df1$var1 <- addNA(df1$var1)

df1$isNaCol <- ifelse(df1$var1 == NA, 1, 0);summary(df1$isNaCol)
df1$isNaCol <- ifelse(is.na(df1$var1), 1, 0);summary(df1$isNaCol)
df1$isNaCol <- ifelse(df1$var1 == 'NA', 1, 0);summary(df1$isNaCol)
df1$isNaCol <- ifelse(df1$var1 == '<NA>', 1, 0);summary(df1$isNaCol)
```

Also when I type `??addNA` I don't get any matches. Is this a gray-market function or something?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, `any(is.na(as.character(df1$var1)))` returns `TRUE`... But I'm not sure why it isn't working directly... `x=factor('a'); x[1]=NA; addNA(x); is.na(x)` returns `TRUE` is it should...

Comment: @Justin when you set `x[1]=NA`, you're setting the level index to NA, not the value. See `as.numeric(x)` vs `as.numeric(df1$var1)`. `is.na` looks at the level indexes.

Answer (score 5):

Testing equality to `NA` with the usual comparison operators always yields `NA`---you want `is.na`. Additionally, calling `is.na` on a `factor` test each level index (not the value associated with that index), so you want to convert the `factor` to a `character` vector first.

```
df1$isNaCol <- ifelse(is.na(as.character(df1$var1)), 1, 0);summary(df1$isNaCol)
```

Comment: @GavinSimpson see my comment on the question. Something is different about our setups. I don't get the output in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Note that this is done with the OP's data *before* the call to `addNA()`**.

It is instructive to see what `addNA()` does with this data.

```
> head(df1$var1)
[1] <NA> def  ghi  jkl  <NA> def 
Levels: abc def ghi jkl
> levels(df1$var1)
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi" "jkl"
> head(addNA(df1$var1))
[1] <NA> def  ghi  jkl  <NA> def 
Levels: abc def ghi jkl <NA>
> levels(addNA(df1$var1))
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi" "jkl" NA
```

`addNA` is altering the *levels* of the factor such that missing-ness (`NA`) is a level where by default R ignores it as what level the `NA` values take is, of course, missing. It is also stripping out the `NA` information - in a sense it is no longer unknown but part of a category "missing".

To look at the help for `addNA` us `?addNA`.

If we look at the definition of `addNA` we see that all it is doing is altering the levels

```
of the factor, not changing the data any:

> addNA
function (x, ifany = FALSE) 
{
    if (!is.factor(x)) 
        x <- factor(x)
    if (ifany & !any(is.na(x))) 
        return(x)
    ll <- levels(x)
    if (!any(is.na(ll))) 
        ll <- c(ll, NA)
    factor(x, levels = ll, exclude = NULL)
}
```

Note that it doesn't otherwise change the data - the `NA` are still there in the factor. We can replicate most of the behaviour of `addNA` via:

```
with(df1, factor(var1, levels = c(levels(var1), NA), exclude = NULL))

> head(with(df1, factor(var1, levels = c(levels(var1), NA), exclude = NULL)))
[1] <NA> def  ghi  jkl  <NA> def 
Levels: abc def ghi jkl <NA>
```

**However because `NA` is now a level, those entries are *not* indicated as being missing via `is.na()`** That explains the second comparison you do not working (where you use `is.na()`).

The only nicety you get from `addNA` is that it doesn't add `NA` as a level if it already exists as one. Also, via the `ifany` you can stop it adding `NA` as a level if there are no `NA`s in the data.

Where you are going wrong is attempting to compare an `NA` with something using the usual comparison methods (except your second example). If we don't know what value and `NA` observation takes, how can we compare it with something? Well, we can't, other than with the internal representation of `NA`. This is what is done by the `is.na()` function:

```
> with(df1, head(is.na(var1), 10))
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Hence I would do (without using `addNA` *at all*)

```
df1 <- transform(df1, isNaCol = is.na(var1))

> head(df1)
  id y var1 var2 var3 isNaCol
1  1 1 <NA> ab c  abc    TRUE
2  2 0  def  ghi  ghi   FALSE
3  3 0  ghi  jkl  nop   FALSE
4  4 0  jkl  def  xyz   FALSE
5  5 0 <NA> ab c  abc    TRUE
6  6 1  def  ghi  ghi   FALSE
```

If you want that as a `1`, `0`, variable, just add `as.numeric()` as in

```
df1 <- transform(df1, isNaCol = as.numeric(is.na(var1)))
```

Where I think you are really going wrong is in wanting to attach an `NA` level to the factor. I see `addNA()` as a convenience function for use in things like `table()`, and even that has arguments to not need the prior use of `addNA()`, e.g.:

```
> with(df1, table(var1, useNA = "ifany"))
var1
 abc  def  ghi  jkl <NA> 
   0   50   50   50   50
```

Comment: I get different output for `with(df1, head(is.na(var1), 10))` (all `FALSE`)

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Not here. I just rebuilt from the OP's data to check. And restarted R to check. Also this is what `is.na()` has been doing for as long as I can remember. There is no labels vs levels issue here - the value is `NA` and `is.na()` informs you of that.

Comment: hmm...what version of R (3.0.1 here)? I just restarted vanilla and get the same output as before.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde `R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)`

Comment: @GavingSimpson well that makes a lot of sense. I assume you tried it with a clean session?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Yes, restarted to check. Are you running this *after* `addNA` has been called? or before? I am not running the `addNA` step as that seems superfluous to what the OP wants.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde And yes, I see now: Try `is.na(addNA(df1$var1))` and you'll see the issue. `addNA` is getting rid of the `NA` information.

Comment: after. It's not superfluous. It adds NA as a level, replacing the NA indexes with the index of the NA level. See `as.numeric(df1$var1)` before and after the `addNA` step. So if you want to have NA as a level, you'd need to convert to character before doing what OP wants.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Right, by superfluous I really don't see why `addNA` needs to come into this. By making `NA` a level you effectively said that it isn't `NA` but part of a category `NA` (or missing - not stated say). In which case `is.na()` is right, if confusing, when it states that no values are `NA` *in the factor*. I don't see the point in adding `NA` in a persistent manner here - perhaps this is just an artificial example or one small part of a larger analysis, but it seems to me that `addNA` is perhaps best used on the fly where you want to include `NA` as a level and hence counted.

Comment: agreed. Well, if OP needs NA as a level or not, he has an answer for each case.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Indeed. The discussion is perhaps one of semantics. I feel you have Answered the question as posed though, whereas I answer a different question, one which seems more natural to me, but perhaps not to the OP :-)

Answer (score 4):

Anything compared to NA is NA; this is why your first summary is all NA.

The `addNA` function changes any NA observations in your factor to a new level. This level is then given the *label* NA (of character mode). The underlying variable itself no longer has any NAs. This is why your second summary is all 0.

To see how many observations have the NA level, use what Matthew Plourde posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm amazed such a simple question doesn't have a simple answer. I ran into the same situation I needed NA levels for a subset of my data pipeline. It turns out `is.na()` works on the levels but not on the factor variable is itself. So my solution is based on that.

```
# create a factor variable with two levels and missing values
set.seed(1)
x <- factor(sample(c(0,1,NA), size = 10, replace = T))

x
#[1] 0    <NA> 0    1    0    <NA> <NA> 1    1    <NA>
#Levels: 0 1

# is.na works...
is.na(x)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

# add NA as a level
x <- addNA(x)
x
#[1] 0    <NA> 0    1    0    <NA> <NA> 1    1    <NA>
#Levels: 0 1 <NA>

# is.na doesn't work...
is.na(x)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# get the level that is NA
na_level <- which(is.na(levels(x))) # 3

# Same as if using is.na() before using addNA()
!x %in% (levels(x)[-na_level])
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```