# Subset dataframe after addNA of an factor

Tags: r, subset, na

I've got a dataframe with a continuous variable x and a grouping factor. I need to add `NA` as a factor level for some reason. As a result, the data is:

```
df <- data.frame(x= 1:4, group= factor(c(NA, 1, 1, 2)))
df$group <- addNA(df$group)
```

How can I now subset the data in the "group" variable for the `NA` values? I attempted:

```
df[df$group == "NA", ]
df[df$group == "<NA>", ]
df[is.na(df$group), ]
df[df$group == levels(df$group)[3], ]
```

My expected output contains all rows where `df$group` has factor level `NA`, i.e. `data.frame(x= 1:4, group= factor(c(NA, 1, 1, 2)))[1, ]`.

I do need to add `NA` as factor level since it is pretty handy in my situation (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214141/aggregate-by-na-in-r) for one case where it is useful).

Comment: What is your desired outcome? Could you give an example?

Comment: @FrancescoGrossetti Hello, as written in the question "My expected output contains all rows where df$group has factor level NA, i.e. data.frame(x= 1:4, group= addNA(factor(c(NA, 1, 1, 2))))[1, ]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
df[is.na(as.character(df$group)),]
  x group
  1  <NA>
```

moving the variable to character before looking for na values

Comment: Also, this may be of your interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302053/find-na-values-after-using-addna